# Python __import__ specific submodules, depending in which software we are

Tags: python, import, reload

I need little help with importing modules in python. So.. Without unnecessary chatter:

I have specific structure of directories and modules:

- multisoft/

  - Core/
  - __init__.py
  - Soft1/

    - __init__.py
    - Controls.py
    - Rigs.py
  - MySoft/

    - __init__.py
    - Controls.py
    - Rigs.py

Now from the user point of view, you only import:

```
import multisoft.Core as MSC
```

And e.g. you should get access to submodules by:

```
MSC.Controls.someFunction()
```

This module can be used in different softwares, and from user from point of view it doesn't matter in which software you are. Using of this module is the same. Of course the implementation of submodules, are differ from one software to another.

And I have some constraints which I have to keep. Basically every module can have more or less files. And the __all__ 
variable must be taken into consideration in every software implementation:

- MySoft/__init__.py
- Soft1/__init__.py

(in those init's files you put __all__ variable: __all__ = ['Controls', 'Rigs'])

I produced a part of code which basically do what I want to do:

Core/__init__.py

```
import os
import sys

def _softRecognize():

    if youAreInSoft1():
        directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
        sys.path.insert(0,directory)
        module = __import__('Soft1', fromlist=['*'])
        globals().update(vars(module))


_softRecognize()
```

But I can't reload this module, and this is one of constraint which I must keep.

```
import multisoft.Core as MSC
reload(MSC)

# Error: reload(): module Soft1 not in sys.modules
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# ImportError: reload(): module Soft1 not in sys.modules #
```

Thanks for any help

All the Best
Kamil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are trying to abstract the interface. There are two ways to do this, either conditional imports, or variable assignments:

```
# Conditional
if youAreInSoft1(): 
    import Soft1.Controls as Controls
    import Soft1.Rigs as Rigs
else:
    import Soft2.Controls as Controls
    import Soft2.Rigs as Rigs

reload(Controls)
reload(Rigs)

#Variable
import Soft1 as _soft1
import Soft2 as _soft2

Controls = None
Rigs = None

global Controls, Rigs

if youAreInSoft1():
    Controls = _soft1.Controls
    Rigs = _soft1.Controls
else:
    Controls = _soft2.Controls
    Rigs = _soft2.Controls

reload(Controls)
reload(Rigs)
```

In either case, you also need to have the submodules reload whatever they need as well, i.e. reloading Controls will have to reload its submodules on down as well, if you want that behaviour.

Comment: Hi Corley,

Thanks for your answer, your solution works nicely. I think that I complicated too much my script. I wanted some "procedural" functionality to avoid writting by hand every import in Core/\__init__.py

I think your solution is better because it's more simpler and it works :-)